# DataTables warning: table id={id} - Ajax error

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, datatable

i am trying to bind json to table using datatable
here is my code Html

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="dataTables-1">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Customer Site Id</th>
                                        <th>Customer Product name</th>
                                        <th>Start Date Time</th>
                                        <th>Stop Date Time</th>
                                        <th>Upload</th>
                                        <th>Download</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody></tbody>
                            </table>
```

and here is script of datatable

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            $("#btnFilter").click(function () {
                //var tab = $("#Tab").val().length;
                //var fromDate = $("#FromModel").val();
                //var toDate = $("#ToDate").val();

                CreateTableUsage();

            });

            function CreateTableUsage() {
                $('#dataTables-1').DataTable({
                    searching: false,
                    'bAutoWidth': false,
                    sAjaxSource: '@Url.Action("Filter") + ?tab=' + encodeURI($('#Tab').val()) + encodeURI($('#FromModel').val()) + encodeURI($('#ToDate').val()),
                    aoColumns: [
            { "sName": "SiteRefId", "bSortable": false },
            { "sName": "CustomerServiceRefId", "bSortable": false },
            { "sName": "StartTimeUtc", "bSortable": false },
            { "sName": "StopTimeUtc", "bSortable": false },
            { "sName": "CallingStationId", "bSortable": false },
            { "sName": "IpAddress", "bSortable": false }]
                });
            }
        </script>
```

here is code BackEnd

```
public ActionResult Filter(string tab, string FromDate, string ToDate)
{
   return Json(new { aaData = lUsage.Select( x => new object[] { x.SiteRefId, x.CustomerServiceRefId, x.StartTimeUtc , x.StopTimeUtc, x.CallingStationId, x.IpAddress}).ToList() }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

when action return the json to view, it raise a error of datatable 
DataTables warning: table id={id} - Ajax error

Comment: You need to specify [**mData**](http://legacy.datatables.net/ref) property for each column of DataTable which tells datatable to which column it bind data.

Comment: Besides of `mData`, there is `mRender` property which can be used together to render column content into HTML. Also ensure that column names are comply with corresponding JSON property names.

Comment: i add mData but still have same error

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to do like bellow on one of your Datatable Option.

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "destroy": true
} );
```

It caused by reinitialising datatable as you see on the error message.
The destroy option is for it.